# Windows 10 messes up the dual boot of SSD w/ UEFI firmware failing to detect it

Tags: linux, windows, boot, uefi

My SSD drive on an HP desktop with UEFI firmware [Nov 2016] is loaded with dual boot of Xubuntu and Windows 10, but when Windows 10 shuts down and is booted again, it boots directly to Windows 10 without showing the dual boot options. After I disable the Fast Startup option in Control Panel, the issue keeps occurring, then I use boot-repair and the dual boot option shows up again; however, after using Windows 10, the same issue begins again.

I use a USB stick with Xubuntu to boot the PC, then install boot-repair from the internet, however, since I meet this issue so often, I decided to make a live-USB disk of Boot-Repair-Disk, and the bad problem happens after I use the Boot-Repair-Disk to boot the PC to fix the missing dual-boot issue:

- it first reports some errors of the UEFI firmware, then reports no SSD found
- if I try to reboot the PC with the USB stick of Xubuntu to run boot-repair, it reports the same errors

How can I access the SSD again to see what happens and/or what else should I try *(I hope to find some kind of low-level USB scanning tools for detecting the SSD first)*?

Answer (score 1):

Both *Windows* [Fast Startup](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup) and *BIOS* [Fast Boot](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000006699/intel-nuc.html) options should be disabled on dual-boot PC's because they store information on the current system state on shutdown, [marking the disk volume as "dirty"](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/manually-reset-or-clear-dirty-bit-in-windows-without-chkdsk/). That means, when rebooting, BIOS directs the boot from the last OS used *only*.

BTW, though not asked in the question, most modern Linux distros work well with Secure Boot *enabled*, so that option in the UEFI firmware should be left enabled.

Comment: BIOS Fast Boot at my pc is disabled; so this is not the reason for this case; still the SSD is missing; can't access it anyway now.

Answer (score 0):

First, I have 3 questions to ask:-

1. Have you installed the *UEFI* version of *xubuntu* on your device?
2. Do you have *Grub* bootloader or any similar bootloader installed?
3. Do you have *secure boot* enabled?

If your answer is either yes or no. Then try these steps:-

•If you do not have a bootloader try installing one. There are a plethora of tutorials on how to install it.

•If you have one try entering the bios and changing the boot drive from *Windows Boot Manager* to ubuntu/Grub (and similar).

•Or try enabling Intel SGX from the bios of you have a Intel processor. This might help with the errors.

•Or try installing the *latest* firmware for the **bios**.

•Try updating the *bootloader*.

***Hope it helps.***

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).